# Point of instantiation of default arguments in a template function

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, instantiation, name-lookup

The standard allows function templates to be instantiated after the enclosing namespace-scope declaration or at the end of the translation unit when they are referred to from a non-template context: [[temp.point]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.point#1)

> For a function template specialization, a member function template
>   specialization, or a specialization for a member function or static
>   data member of a class template, if the specialization is implicitly
>   instantiated because it is referenced from within another template
>   specialization and the context from which it is referenced depends on
>   a template parameter, the point of instantiation of the specialization
>   is the point of instantiation of the enclosing specialization.
>   **Otherwise, the point of instantiation for such a specialization immediately follows the namespace scope declaration or definition that
>   refers to the specialization.**

[[temp.point]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.point#8)

> A specialization for a function template, a member function template,
>   or of a member function or static data member of a class template may
>   have multiple points of instantiations within a translation unit, and
>   in addition to the points of instantiation described above, **for any
>   such specialization that has a point of instantiation within the
>   translation unit, the end of the translation unit is also considered a
>   point of instantiation.** A specialization for a class template has at
>   most one point of instantiation within a translation unit. A
>   specialization for any template may have points of instantiation in
>   multiple translation units. If two different points of instantiation
>   give a template specialization different meanings according to the
>   one-definition rule, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic
>   required.

Now consider this minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
struct A {};
std::array<char, 2> show(float, A)
{
    std::cout << "2\n";
    return {};
}
template<typename T>
struct Fun {
    decltype(show(0, T{})) b;
};
template <typename T>
void func(T, int c = sizeof(Fun<T>{}.b))
{
    show(0, T{});
    std::cout << c << '\n';
}
int main()
{
    func(A{});
}
char show(int, A)
{
    std::cout << "1\n";
    return {};
}
```

Both GCC and Clang output `1` `2` ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/2FDf-6)).

Here, the instantiation of `func<A>` (triggered in `main`) has two points of instantiation: one immediately after `main` (and thus before the second `show`) and another at the end of the translation unit.  The first `1` indicates that the compilers to instantiate `func<A>` at the end of the translation unit.  However, the default argument `sizeof(Fun<T>{}.b)` causes `Fun<A>` to be instantiated, and the second `2` suggests that `Fun<A>` is instantiated before the second `show`.

Now, the point of instantiation of default arguments is specified to be that of `func<A>`: [[temp.point]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.point#2)

> If a function template or member function of a class template is
>   called in a way which uses the definition of a default argument of
>   that function template or member function, **the point of
>   instantiation of the default argument is the point of instantiation of
>   the function template or member function specialization.**

Hmm ...  This seems to suggest that the two numbers should be the same.

I feel I'm missing something here.  Is there any detail that I happened to neglect?  Or did I make mistakes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As quoted in the question [[temp.point]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp#point-8) says:

> If two different points of instantiation give a template specialization different meanings according to the one-definition rule, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

According to the one-definition rule two definitions are not the same if function call overload resolution of a name used in the definition will yield different entities defined outside the definition. ([[basic.def.odr]/6.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def.odr#6.2))

Overload resolution of the two calls to `show` in `func<A>` and in `Fun<A>` will choose different function overloads depending on whether `func<A>`'s point of instantiation is immediately after `main` or at the end of the translation unit, both of which are allowed points of instantiation.

Therefore the program is *ill-formed, no diagnostic required*.

Comment: But how do you interpret when you comment out `std::array<char, 2> show(float, A)` function,the `show ` in `func<A>` can be overloaded,however the `show` in `Fun<A>` will be ill-formed,if `Fun<T>{}` and `func<A>` are at the same point of instantiation,the `show` in `func<A>` would be ill-formed too.

Comment: @jackX I am not sure I understand your comment correctly. Maybe post it as a new question if I didn't. If you remove the first `show` overload, then I would say the program is still *ill-formed, no diagnostic required*, because if the point of instantiation of `func<A>` is directly after `main`, then both `show` lookups will fail, but if it is at the end of the translation unit, then lookup will succeed for both (since `Fun<A>`'s point of instantiation is immediately before that of `func<A>`). So the quoted passage seems to again apply, I think.

Comment: Sorry,I think you haven't got what I mean. Actually,what I want to express is that comment out `std::array<char, 2> show(float, A)` and `int c = sizeof(Fun<T>{}.b)`,only left  `show(0, T{});` inner `func `,the compiler will select `char show(int, A)` for `show(0, A{});`,it prove that the point of instantiation for `show(0, A{})` is always at the end of translation unit,otherwise the program would be ill-formed.If you remain `int c = sizeof(Fun<T>{}.b)` and comment out `show(0, T{});`,the program will be ill-formed,It seems that the point of instantiation for `Fun<A>` is after `main`.

Comment: So I think the point of instantiation of `Fun<A>` is not as the same as that of `func <A>`.It seems to violate the rules what the standard said.

Comment: If I haven't express clearly.Codes can  do.[comment default argument](https://godbolt.org/z/XCHkxn) will prove that  the point of instantiation of `show(0, A{})` is always at the end of translation unit.[remain default argument](https://godbolt.org/z/MUg4Hb) will prove that the point of instantiation of `Fun<A>` is always after `main` and before `char show(int, A)`.Hence It prove that what I aforementioned.

Comment: @jackX I think the compiler is allowed to choose either point of instantiation in either program and if any of them would make the program ill-formed, then I think the paragraph from my answer applies and the program is *ill-formed, no diagnostic required*. So I think both of your linked programs are also *ill-formed, no diagnostic required* and that means the programs may or may not compile without error. I think there is no way to determine which of the possible points of instantiation was chosen. But as I said, feel free to open a new question about it.

Comment: yes,it's the question itself.The compiler select different point of instantiation for `show<A>` and  `Fun<A>`.So it's violation of the rules.the poi of `show<A>` and `Fun<A>` should be either all after `main` or all at the end of translation unit.However according to the result,One is after `main` and the other is at the end of translation unit.So it seems to be violation of  **the point of instantiation of the default argument is the point of instantiation of the function template or member function specialization** rules